# In a directive's onclick, invoke a function "pointer"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Imagine these uses of a directive (in one HTML file):

```
<my-dir function="callMe()"/>
<my-dir function="someOtherFunction()"/>
```

Here's the important bit of the directive:

```
 .directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            function: '&'
        },
    };
})
```

Here's the template HTML:

```
<div ng-click="function(5)">click here</div>
```

This does not work - While `#function` does indeed invoke `#callMe` and `#someOtherFunction`, there seems to be no way to pass the argument.  How can I pass a method to the directive so that the directive can invoke the function and pass an argument?

It's pretty clear the HTML could simply refer to `#callMe` directly.  But then the directive would not work for `#someOtherFunction`

**EDIT - [Here's a fiddle I was working on](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyennis/hp11t65g/11/)**. I amended it with PSL's suggestions. It seems to work now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:-

Specify the name of the argument in the directive `arg`:-

```
<my-dir callback="func1(arg)"></my-dir>
<my-dir callback="func2(arg)"></my-dir>
```

On your template provide the key value pair with the same key name as that of the function.

```
template:'<div ng-click="callback({arg:5})">click here</div>'
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qqZBmz?p=preview)**

`ng-onclick` should be `ng-click` unless you are using some other angular component which provide an `ng-onclick` directive. Use closing tags for your directive elements.

Comment: Hah, I if you see my comment below you can see that I have *also* been waiting to figure out what's going on here. Name the argument, then call it with a param object. That's totally clear now, I sure wish that was somewhere in the ng documents on directives and & scope.

Comment: Thanks PSL.  So, how did you know this?  One of my problems with Angular is that I don't know how to figure things out. I hit dead ends, and that's that.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I was that way too... :) Actually i had gone through same issue some time back did not find out this being documented. Actually ng-documentation does not cover everything, that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typoes and misspellings in the question. Things were correct in the fiddle - I banged this question out quickly.  I typed up one last night that was more detailed but got no takers.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YQgijS?p=preview

The relevant bits:

- I have no idea why this works, and I feel like it indicates there's something weird about & scope that I haven't learned yet.
- When passing the variable in to the directive via an & scope, pass `theFunction` and not `theFunction()`
- When calling the function in an ng-click, call `fun()(args)` instead of `fun(args)`

I know, weird, right? I'm sure there's something going on there. I asked a SO question about it a while ago, but got no response.